# In C++, is a const method returning a pointer to a non-const object considered bad practice?

Tags: c++, const-correctness

In C++, is a const method returning a pointer to a non-const object considered bad practice? For example. consider the following methods:

```
// Makes perfect sense
bool isActive() const { return m_isActive; }

// Makes perfect sense, both consts ensure nothing is modified
const SomeObject* someObject() const { return m_someObject; }

// Makes perfect sense, no const because SomeObject is mutable,
// thus MyClass is indirectly mutable
SomeObject* someObject() { return m_someObject; }

// Makes no sense, if you're just returning a pointer to a const object,
// then the method should clearly be const since nothing can be modified
const SomeObject* someObject() { return m_someObject; }
```

The last combination puzzles me: is the following considered bad practice?

```
SomeObject* someObject() const { return m_someObject; }
```

Because the class that method returns is not const, but the method is, it is somewhat pointless since you could modify `SomeObject` and thus *indirectly* modify your class... so is that form considered bad practice? e.g. should you only use one of the following in place of it?

```
const SomeObject* someObject() const { return m_someObject; }
SomeObject* someObject() { return m_someObject; }
```

---

Real-world situation: I'm writing a smartphone game which has a `Game` class. The `Game` class contains several methods which return pointers to utility classes like `InputManager`, `AudioManager`, etc.

```
class Game
{
public:
    InputManager* inputManager() const { return m_inputManager; }
    ...

private:
    InputManager* m_inputManager;
    ...
}
```

Does it make ANY sense at all to make `inputManager()` const, since the object it returns is not? (and should not be, since the `InputManager` needs to be mutable for its state to be updated, etc.)

Or should I remove the method's `const` modifier to more accurately reflect the method's behavior? That way if I had a `const Game`, I couldn't call `inputManager()` and then mess with the `Game`'s input manager even though the `Game` was `const`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on whether the non-const pointer is pointing to something inside the const object, or whether it is newly allocated memory that is meant to be variable.

Consider something that returned a copy of a string; it's fine for the returned copy to be non-const, even if the original string is const.  The ownership of the copy is being passed from the method to the calling code; ensuring that the copy is appropriately destructed is now the calling code's problem (quite possibly a very minor problem).

However, it would be a very bad idea to return a non-const pointer to something from inside a const object.

Comment: If object A "owns" object B, and you want to treat A as const, then an accessor to B should also be const. If A doesn't own B, then all bets are off. As the OP points out, it's a stylistic issue in C++. A more pedantic language would enforce this.

Answer (score 2):

That's perfectly acceptable. A const method means that you're not modifying the object whose method you're calling - it does not say anything about any other objects. Of course, that object could be part of "this", or it could be "this" - but that's beyond the point.

"const" in general is more of a promise than anything, but the underlying idea is the same - a const method says that "this" is const, and that's about all.

Comment: Well, not even so much that `this` is constant, so much as I won't modify `this` using this particular method. I think that's what you're saying in this first paragraph, but it seemed a little unclear. Const is generally a promise not to change something through the particular means that is marked const. For pointer-to-const, reference-to-const etc, the referenced object very often is non-const through some other reference and modified through that. Const references in member data are often a case in point - a promise that the class won't modify the object it references, but nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, returning a pointer of member is a bad idea, whether const or not.

When an object return a handle of its private member, others can change the private member through this handle. The state of object might be inconsistence and cause lots of trouble. Even if there is a const, caller still can use const cast to bypass this check. So it is not a good idea to return handle of any private member of object.

Comment: If a user of your class uses `const_cast` to circumvent the protections you laid out, then they deserve whatever trouble they get.

Comment: @Dennis I completely agree. As a side-note, another response I give to people who think languages like C# and Java not having `const` is A Good Thing™ when they say that `const` is useless because people can use `const_cast` is "reflection". One word. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `const` matter much here.

It's normally thrown upon to return a handle (pointer, reference) to an attribute:

- it ties users to a particuler implementation, making it impossible to change it
- it makes it impossible to enforce invariants (non-const versions), you may not have such now, but you never now what the future will give

If you begin making attributes directly accessible, they are as good as `public`.

Examples:

```
class Foo
{
public:
  std::vector<Bar> const& bars() const; // Ooops, impossible to move to a `deque`
                                        // or to enable polymorphic behavior
private:
  std::vector<Bar> mBars;
};
```

You're better off returning by value, this way if you change your internals you can always provide a new method and make some conversion in the old one not to break your interface (marking it deprecated and all).

Remember: people have been sent to jail for exposing their privates!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the `Game` and `InputManager` objects seem to be singletons. If this is the case, you only need to assure, that only one instance of Game (containing only one InputManager) exist, and skip const decorators. As suggested above, In this case, I would return a reference to the contained objects, no pointers.